# What is NumberFormatInfo.NativeDigits used for?

Tags: c#, localization, globalization, cultureinfo

Consider the following code:

```cs
const int value = int.MaxValue;
CultureInfo culture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("bn-IN");

Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", culture.NumberFormat.NativeDigits));
Console.WriteLine(value.ToString(culture));
Console.WriteLine(value.ToString(culture.NumberFormat));
```

Result

> ০,১,২,৩,৪,৫,৬,৭,৮,৯
>
> 2147483647
>
> 2147483647

In this example, `NativeDigits` was not used to format the number, as in both cases they were formatted using 0-9

What then are `NativeDigits` used for?

Comment: Did you read the remarks section [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.nativedigits?view=net-7.0#remarks)?

Comment: @DavidG (facepalm) no, I didn't. I'm still curious to know if there are any usages of `NativeDigits` anywhere in the framework, and if so, what for.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but I suspect not.

Comment: I can't see anything in the [runtime](https://github.com/search?q=repo%3Adotnet%2Fruntime+NativeDigits&type=code) at least.